# I am trying to add a new value to an existing custom option programmatically but not happening

Tags: magento-1.9

I am able to get all the values but not able to add new 
tried an answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798158/how-to-update-custom-options-programatically-in-magento) but doesn't seems to work

```
$obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product_id = $obj->getIdBySku('WSW01943');
$product = $obj->load($product_id);

$collection = $product->getOptions();
foreach ($collection as $value) {
    $optionType = $value->getType();
    if ($optionType=="radio") {
        $values = $value->getValues();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain me what you need ?

Comment: I solved it, basically I had a custom option of type radio button, which already had two values, and I wanted to add additional values programmaticaly, because I needed this operation to be done on more than 1000 products at once.

Comment: Great news :) Please answer here. it will helpful for other and change as accept for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this

```
$obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product_id = $obj->getIdBySku('12365');
$product = $obj->load($product_id);

$options = $product->getOptions();
foreach ($options as $option) {
$optionType = $option->getType();
    if ($optionType=="radio") {
       $bgn = array(
            'title' => 'custom size',
            'sort_order' => 5,
            'price' =>140,
            'price_type' => 'fixed',
            );

        $valueInstance = $option->getValueInstance()->unsetValues();
        $valueInstance->addValue($bgn);
        $valueInstance->setOption($option)->saveValues();
    }
}
```